# Retrofit RxJava doesn't make multiple calls (Android)

Tags: android, get, retrofit2, rx-java, okhttp

I am trying to make repetitive calls with a timeout of 5 seconds with Retrofit2 on Android. The interface:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import io.reactivex.Observable
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


interface YooApiService {

@GET("payment/getInfo.php")
fun search(@Query("q") query: String,
           @Query("apicall") apicall: String): Observable<String>

/**
 * Companion object to create the GithubApiService
 */
companion object Factory {
    fun create(): YooApiService {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("https://pros.sbs/")

        builder.client(httpClient.build())

        val retrofit = builder.build()

        return retrofit.create(YooApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Search Repository

```
import io.reactivex.Observable

class SearchRepository(val apiService: YooApiService) {
    fun searchUsers(id: String): Observable<String> {
        return apiService.search(query = id, apicall = "status")
    }
}
```

Function which I call in my Activity:

```
private fun payment(id: String) {
    val repository = SearchRepositoryProvider.provideSearchRepository()
    repository.searchUsers(id)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe ({
                status : String ->
            if (status == "succeeded") {
                // do staff
            }
        }, { error ->
            Log.i(TAG, error.message!!)
        })
}
```

The thing is, only one call is made after function initialization. How can I fix this so that multiple calls were made? Thank you!

Comment: In error check inseadOf timeout exception then call the same method again

Comment: Sorry, how can I implement "insteadOf" you mentioned?

Comment: if(error is TimeoutException){
            payment(PASS_YOUR_ID)
        }
Note:  when the same issue occur, Calls happen repeatedly

Comment: so it will be a recurrent function, as we call the method inside inself? I tried what you said, but it didn't work

Comment: If you've issue with above... Listen using livedata call this method from your activity